# Issues with Back Button in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application and i am having issues with the back button which all phones has. if i click the back button of my phone it redirects me to the previous login page with all credentials filled in and allows me to log in again, which is obviously not secure. Can someone help me out ? Any extra codes which should be added to prevent user from getting access to previous page with autofilled data.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `finish()` as soon as you leave your `LoginActivity`, something like:

---

Inside your `LoginActivity` (when login has been successful)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // This will remove your LoginActivity from the stack
```

---

Another alternative would be to set your EditTexts to empty right after you start the `SecondActivity`

```
EditText editTextUser = findViewById(R.id.user); // Assuming you have these already
EditText editTextPass = findViewById(R.id.pass);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
editTextUser.setText("");
editTextPass.setText("");
```

Comment: Any other alternatives to go back to the previous page without the filled in forms ?

Comment: Added another alternative by clearing the EditText after leaving the Activity, you could also clear them in the `onStop()`

Answer (score 0):

You could either choose which page to go on back pressed

```
Public void onBackPressed()
{
    IntentName.setClass(getApplicationContext(activityname.class);
    StartActivity(intentName);
}
```

Or  just create an empty function and then nothing will happen on back pressed

```
Public void onBackPressed()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

}
```

Make sure that when changing the activity you clean the forms, so when they return they will be empty.

Information about flags [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)